# Solving trigonometric equations: do I need to consider different cases in this example?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve this set of trigonometric equations:
\begin{align} 
\begin{aligned}
\tan\left(\frac{\delta+\beta}{2}\right) &= c\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\
b\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\delta-\beta}{2}\right) &= a\\
\cos\left(\frac{\delta+\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right) &= \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
Where a,b,c and $\theta$ are some given (but random) real numbers (they could be $0$ and $\pi$). The goal is to solve for the real values of $\gamma,\beta$ and $\delta$. I'm trying to solve these equations by combining some variables. Let
\begin{align}
M = \frac{\delta+\beta}{2}, N = \frac{\delta-\beta}{2}, P = \frac{\gamma}{2}
\end{align}
then it's easy to solve for $M$ from equation $1$. However, to solve for $\delta$ and $\beta$, we also need to figure out $N$. I'm worried that if I need to discuss the solutions by cases, like if $\theta = \pi$ (so that $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$ is undefined) or if $a$ or $b$ is equal to $0$. Any suggestions on solving for this question? Is it possible to obtain a generalized solution? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:
$$M+N=\delta$$
$$M-N=\beta$$

You can find $M,N$ from your first two equations, and then calculate $\delta,\beta$ from those.

For $\gamma$, note that $$\tan^2(\alpha)+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}$$
From this, you can write $$\cos\alpha=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan^2\alpha+1}}$$
(depending on the angle).

Then this:
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\delta+\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
$$
Becomes this:

$$\cos\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cdot\sqrt{\tan^2(\frac{\delta+\beta}{2})+1}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Should $M+N = \delta$?

Comment: Oops. Fixed it. Cheers!